# Set "Target Audiences" field with multiple values on a List Item

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, audience

I am attempting to set the "Target Audiences" field on a list item programmatically.  I have been able to set the value programmatically for one audience, but when I attempt to use multiple audiences, SharePoint tries to interpret the value I am setting as a single audience, rather than multiple.  I am setting the value using the code below.

```
listItem[listItem.Fields["Target Audiences"].InternalName] = "Audience One";
```

I use this code to specify multiple audiences like so:

```
listItem[listItem.Fields["Target Audiences"].InternalName] = "Audience One; Audience Two";
```

When I do this, SharePoint tries to interpret the entire string as a single audience, and I get a message when I edit the list item that says `"No exact match was found."`

Am I using the correct format for specifying multiple audiences for this field, or is there a class that I should be using similar to `SPFieldLookupValue`?

Comment: Kyle, could you post what your final solution was? I am facing the same problem as you.

Comment: Can u please post your final solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized I never came back and answered this.

I ended up storing the names of the audiences in a column attached to each list item, then querying the object model to see if the current user is a member of those audiences.  This worked for me because I was pulling the data from the list item in a custom web part, and the user never saw the actual list item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to save multiple audiences in a SPListItem, but if I had this problem, I'd try to print out the value of this field from a PowerShell script. Something like:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint");
$site = Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://yourserver");
$web = $site.openweb();
$list = $web.lists["YourList"];
$item = $list.getitembyid(itemid);
write-output $item["Target Audiences"];
```

EDIT: found some information about what the Audience field value actually is: http://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/1181567/mobile

Comment: I did that, and the value of the script is in this format: GUID,GUID,GUID;;;; (one GUID ID for each audience comma separated, followed by 4 semi colons.)  When I used that format to set the field, and then viewed the field in edit mode, it contained the exact text entered (the guids, followed by 4 semicolons.)

Comment: In other words:  Sharepoint isn't doing any translation on the value set to the field.

Comment: I think, you should read this post, too: http://dotnetmafia.sys-con.com/node/1181567/mobile

Comment: That link is for using audiences on a webpart.  I'm trying to audience a list item.  I have tried exactly what that post says, but since there is no `AuthorizationFilter` property on a list item, I set the formatted string as the value of the `"Target Audiences"` field.

In any case, I have come up with a work around for my issue, and I'll be posting an answer shortly.  I would still like to know if it can be done using OOB SharePoint Audience Targeting, though.